# metamask pending transaction cannot find at MEW

Tags: metamask

need your help. 
While I was sending my eth to somewhere from metamask, it somehow made two different transactions. 1st one was 9.98 eth, and 2nd one was 9.97 eth. 
Since my metamask wallet only had 10 eth, the 1st one (9.98 eth) finally made a transaction after few hours. But the 2nd one (9.97eth) is still pending in my metamask. 
The problem arise from here is that, I can't do other transactions since that 2nd one is still in pending. So, I tried to find from the Internet how I can cancel the transactions and follow. I tried the method that go to the MyEtherWallet and paste the TX Hash. But it tells that the TRANSACTION cannot find. 
TX HASH: 0x51dcd6319ed331a79630fdf766d59f9605e782b183428f82dbdca801e275e118

I don't know how to handle this. Please help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your transaction on Etherscan here:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x51dcd6319ed331a79630fdf766d59f9605e782b183428f82dbdca801e275e118

You can see that this transaction was "dropped and replaced" by another transaction with the same nonce:

[image]

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb073b3658bbdd337cbd18765866a46edf2a216670a9e492b91f220ff085f54f7

The final state of your account can be found here:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1dd3488a85e56764ff3ba6952fff8807f907c4b3

In general, the following behaviors will occur in situations like these:

- If you submit a transaction to the network which is illegal (as in you are trying to send/spend more than you have), the network will reject the transaction
- If you send another transaction with the same nonce, the network will generally prefer to pick up the one with the higher gas price and mine it first. Since transaction nonce can only be used once, that will make all other transactions with the same nonce illegal, and they will be rejected by the network.

You were not able to find the transaction using MEW because the transaction never actually got mined into the blockchain. However, etherscan monitors pending transactions as well, and can provide this kind of information. Note, however, that in your account history, that this rejected transaction is not there. Only with the transaction hash can you really find it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I found one article from the Internet somewhere just after writing this question. And solved it.. And that's you found out the transactions like above photo. What I did... I did manually as someone introduced. and somehow every pending transactions are successfully made in 1 sec. It was quit surprising. I really appreciate your answer. I found out the reason why... ILLEGAL.. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: If there was another set of steps you followed which specifically addressed your issue, you should document those steps in the form of an answer, and mark it as the correct answer so that others who run into the same problem can learn too.